# Chat reply highlight changes margin, interacts poorly with word wrapping

Tags: bug, chat, design

When a chat reply is highlighted, it temporarily changes the right margin, narrowing the message area and in some cases causing the height to change (which makes elements on the page jump):

> [image]

The cause is pretty straightforward. In the chat CSS `.highlight` is styled like this:

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #ff0 !important
}
```

But also, separately, for some reason a margin is added:

```css
.message.highlight {
    margin-right: 48px
}
```

No margin should be specified.

Comment: It looks like it's designed to allow for the timestamp on the right... which also makes me think that the transcript view and the in-room view possibly need slightly different styling. (Just leaving a note here for whoever ends up actually fixing this. :))

Comment: It does kinda look that way, huh. Odd choice, though, since it appears to look [perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIppb.png) with no margins on timestamped containers, in both the chat and transcript views.